# How to read a URL parameter from inside SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Currently I have a URL that has a ?userid=2 at the end.
How do I need to read that and put that into a report parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter named userid (Parameter name is case-censitive) and use in your report:

```
=Parameters!userid.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, create a parameter in your SQL query or stored procedure with a name of userid. This will populate the parameter in the SSRS Parameters. Now, go to your Datasets in your SSRS report and open the Dataset Properties. Go to Parameters section and set the value for the userid parameter to

```
=Parameters!userid.Value
```

The parameter name is case sensitive.